# Spring MVC change <form:select> options dynamically with other <form:select>

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on a Spring MVC platform, and I have encountered a problem.
I wish to allow users to send invites to Conventions and Events that they have added on the platform. I have a `model` for both of those, and they work fine, but when sending an invite to someone, I just can't seem to find a way to dynamically update a `<form:select>` option list.
When a person invites another person to a convention, they have a two dropdown lists. The first one is the convention dropdown list and it contains all the convention the person has added. Each `Convention` has a list of `Event`s, and the second dropdown list should show all events for the selected convention. 
So for each option on the first dropdown list, there should be multiple options on the second dropdown list.

I'll post the models here, if they mean something to you, and cut the code that isn't relevant for this question.

**Event:**

```
 public class Event {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int eventId;
        private int conventionId;
        private String conventionName;

        private String eventName;
        private String eventDescription;
        private String websiteLink, facebookLink, twitterLink, instagramLink, youtubeLink;
        private String eventType;
        private String eventDateFrom;
        private String eventDateTo;
        private String hostedBy;
        private String eventAddress;
        private String eventPr;
  //getters and setters
```

**Convention:**

```
@Entity
public class Convention {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int conventionId;

    private String conventionName;
    private String conventionDescription;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Event> conventionEvents;
    private String websiteLink, facebookLink, twitterLink, instagramLink, youtubeLink;
    private String conventionType;
    private String conPr;
    private String hostedBy;
    private boolean isAccepted;
//getters and setters
```

**Invite:**

```
@Entity
public class Invite {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int inviteId;

    private String senderName;
    private int senderId;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Convention name must not be empty!")
    private String conName;
    private String eventName;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Message must not be empty!")
    private String message;
    private String tripType;
    private String dateFrom;
    private String dateTo;
    private boolean isRead;
    private String sendingTo;
```

**sendInvite.jsp** [EDIT - CHANGED THE CODE]

```
      <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp" %>
    <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sendInvite/{${sendingTo}}" method="post" commandName="invite">
        <form:hidden path="senderName" value="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}"/>
        <form:hidden path="sendingTo" value="${sendingTo}"/>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="eventName">Convention: </label>
        </div>


        <form:select path="conName" name="conName">

            <c:forEach items="${conventionList}" var="convention">
                <form:option value="${convention.conventionName}">${convention.conventionName}</form:option>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>

        <form:select path="eventName">
            <c:forEach items="${eventList}" var="event">
                <c:if test="${event.conventionName == convention.conventionName}">
                    <form:option value="${event.eventName}">${event.eventName}</form:option>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>

//HERE I JUST NEED TO FIND A WAY TO GET " <c:if test="${event.conventionName == convention.conventionName}">" WORKING SINCE I CAN'T GET THE ACTUAL VALUE OF THE CONVENTION NAME.//


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Message body</label>
            <form:textarea path="message" id="message" class="form-Control"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tripType">Trip type</label>

            <form:select path="tripType" name="tripType">
                <form:option value="Paid">Paid</form:option>
                <form:option value="Unpaid">Unpaid</form:option>
                <form:option value="To be agreed">To be agreed</form:option>

            </form:select>
        </div>
        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Send invitation" class="btn btn-default">
    </form:form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you in advance.

[EDIT - Adding InviteController]

```
@Controller
public class InviteController {

    @Autowired
    InviteService inviteService;

    @Autowired
    ProfileService profileService;

    @Autowired
    ConventionService conventionService;

    @Autowired
    EventService eventService;

    @RequestMapping("/sendInvite/{sendingTo}")
    public String sendInvite(@PathVariable("sendingTo") String sendingTo, Model model, Principal principal) {
        Invite invite = new Invite();
        List<Convention> conventionList = conventionService.getConventionsByUsername(principal.getName());
        List<Event> eventList = eventService.getEventListForOwner(principal.getName());
        model.addAttribute("eventList", eventList);
        model.addAttribute("conventionList", conventionList);
        model.addAttribute("invite", invite);

        return "sendInvite";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendInvite/{sendingTo}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sendInvitePost(@ModelAttribute("invite") Invite invite, @PathVariable("sendingTo") String sendingTo, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("sendingTo", sendingTo);
        inviteService.addInvite(invite);
        return "sendInviteSuccess";
    }

}
```

The method names of the services are self explanatory, I simply get a list with some sort of criteria, be it a username or convention.

Answer (score 0):

In your entity you has declared a List of event, then you can access your events like this convetionList.eventName

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="eventName">Event: </label>
    <form:select path="conName" name="conName" items="${conventionList.eventName}"/>
</div>
```

[EDIT]

Try modifying the response from your controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/sendInvite/{sendingTo}")
public String sendInvite(@PathVariable("sendingTo") String sendingTo, Model model, Principal principal) {


    List<Convention> conventionList = conventionService.getConventionsByUsername(principal.getName());
    List<Event> eventList = eventService.getEventListForOwner(principal.getName());

    for(Covention convention : conventionList){

        for(Event event : eventList){

            if(convention.getConventionId() == event.getConventionId())
            {
                convention.conventionEvents.add(event);          

            }
        }


    }
    //Now you have all of your events associated to your conventions
    model.addAttribute("conventionList", conventionList);
    model.addAttribute("invite", new Invite());

    return "sendInvite";
}
```

Now you should be able to use `${conventionList.conventionName}` to get all conventions in your dropdown view and `${conventionList.conventionsEvents.eventName}` and this object should be dinamically displayed by convention

Let me know if you need more help.
Regards,

Comment: No, I can't access a variable of the model that way. I have to have an instance of the object on the JSP page added as a model attribute, and then I can get the value of the variable. The only way I could do such a thing was to declare a var="convention" and then get the eventName from there...
But I don't have a definitive convention on the page, I have a list of conventions.
Thank you anyway.

Comment: At this point, i just need to get " <c:if test="${event.conventionName == convention.conventionName}">" working. Obviously I can't get convention.conventionName since it's out of the <c:forEach> loop, but inputting text in there gave a correct result. Now I just need to find a way to get the value from the option box and compare it to the event.conventionName

Comment: You can't access to event from your convention because you are sending both separately. i'll edit my answer with your controller

Comment: I just tried your edited controller and jsp and I'm just getting an error at line 20: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "eventName"...
It's because it's an object and not a String that should be passed into the database.Also eventName autocompletes a conventions variables, which implies that the list actually has conventions instead of events, which doesn't make sense, since your code seems correct...
There were a few errors I had to fix, like that I'm not allowed to use .equals in the controller. I'm not sure why this is happening...

Comment: in the option value put your eventId then in between your option tag use the eventName

Comment: The problem with equals was my fault, because these methods are primitive int that should be compared with == and equals is for Strings. I'd edited the code again

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. I have tried everything that you have written and also my own version and none of them work. The conventionList doesn't have any events. It's not adding them at all.
I think that the problem is that we add an event to a list of events for a convention, however, we don't add it to the conventionList that is added in the model. Hence, the conventionList is simply the one without any events, gotten from the database.
Could you help me with the controller? :)